# Just fundamental group of a graph of groups vs. fundamental group of a graph of groups with respect to a maximal subtree

Tags: group-theory, geometric-group-theory

On page 87 of the book " Introductory to group theory by Bogopolski", they gave an example of the fundamental group of a graph of groups with respect to a maximal subtree, which I understood well. However, the problem below asks to find the fundamental group of a graph of groups without any mention to a maximal subtree, but I tried to solve it anyway. What changes about finding it without a maximal subtree? Is my way the right one? Thanks for your help!

Question: Find a presentation for the fundamental group of the graph of groups $(\mathbb{G, Y})$ defined as follows. The graph $Y$ is a triangle with 3 vertices $v_{1}, v_{2}, v_{3}$ and 6 edges $e_{j}$, $1\le j\le 6$ with $e_{4}=\overline{e}_{1}, e_{5}=\overline{e}_{2} $ and $e_{6}=\overline{e}_{3}$; the initial vertices are $\alpha(e_{1})=v_{1}, \alpha(e_{2})=v_{2}, \alpha(e_{3})=v_{3}$ and the terminal vertices are $\tau(e_{1})=v_{2}, \tau(e_{2})=v_{3}, \tau(e_{3})=v_{1}$. Let $l,m,n\ge 2$ be integers. The vertex groups and edge groups are $$G_{e_{1}}=G_{\overline{e}_{1}}=\mathbb{Z}_{l}=< a| a^{l} >,$$

$$G_{e_{2}}=G_{\overline{e}_{2}}=\mathbb{Z}_{m}=<b|b^{m}>,$$
 $$G_{e_{3}}=G_{\overline{e}_{3}}=\mathbb{Z}_{n}=<c|c^{n}>,$$
$$G_{v_{1}}=\mathbb{Z}_{n}\oplus\mathbb{Z}_{l}=<c,a|cac^{-1}a^{-1}, c^{n}, a^{l}>,$$ 
 $$G_{v_{2}}=\mathbb{Z}_{l}\oplus \mathbb{Z}_{m}=<a,b|bab^{-1}a^{-1}, a^{l}, b^{m}>,$$
$$G_{v_{3}}=\mathbb{z}_{m}\oplus\mathbb{Z}_{n}=<b,c|bcb^{-1}c^{-1}, b^{m}, c^{n}>.$$
The monomorphisms $\alpha_{e}: G_{e}\to G_{\alpha(e)}$ are the obvious inclusions. For instance, $$\alpha_{e_{1}}:\mathbb{Z}_{l}=G_{e_{1}}\to
 G_{\alpha (e_{1})}=G_{v_{1}}=\mathbb{Z}_{n}\oplus\mathbb{Z}_{l}$$ is given by $\alpha_{e_{1}}(x)=(1,x)$, where $1$ denotes the identity element of $\mathbb{Z}_{n}$.

What I have tried:
$$\pi_{1}(\mathbb{G},Y)=\langle a,b,c,t_{e_{1}}, t_{e_{2}}, t_{e_{3}}|ca^{-1}ca^{-1}, c^{n}, a^{l}, bab^{-1}a^{-1}, b^{m}, bcb^{-1}c^{-1}, t^{-1}_{e_{1}}(1,a)t_{e_{1}}=(a,1), t^{-1}_{e_{2}}(1,b)t_{e_{2}}=(b,1), t^{-1}_{e_{3}}(1,c)t_{e_{3}}=(c,1) \rangle$$

Comment: The way to do it without being given a maximal tree is... first compute a maximal tree.

Comment: @Lee Mosher, how to compute a maximal tree in this particular case? I have been learning the subject.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not given a maximal tree, then you have to compute one for yourself.

You can compute maximal trees, also called "spanning trees", using the [depth first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) algorithm. I'll carry out the algorithm on your example, but, I strongly advise you to *draw a picture* of the graph in order to learn to *see* maximal trees.

A maximal tree $T$ in a connected graph $G$ will contain each vertex. Roughly speaking, the depth first search algorithm builds $T$ inductively, starting with one vertex, and then adding one edge at a time *as long as the new edge connects one vertex already in the graph with another vertex not yet in the graph*. Since $G$ is connected, the algorithm is guaranteed to stop after a number of steps equal to the number of vertices.

We'll build $T$ inductively, starting with

- Step 1: $T_1 = v_1$

Next, we'll ask: whats the first edge that connects $T_1$ to one of the other vertices $v_2,v_3$? The answer is $e_1$, because $\alpha(e_1)=v_1$ and $\tau(e_1)=v_2$. So, we not throw in $v_2$ and $e_1$, and so

- Step 2: $T_2 = v_1 \cup e_1 \cup v_2$

Next, we'll ask: what's the first edge that connects $T_2$ to the remaining vertex $v_3$? The answer is $e_2$, because $\alpha(e_2)=v_2$ and $\tau(e_3)=v_3$, and so

- Step 3: $T = T_3 = v_1 \cup e_1 \cup v_2 \cup e_2 \cup v_3$

and the algorithm is done.

Comment: I have understood the algorithm! So, the maximal subtree contains all vertices and edges of the graph Y except the edge $e_3$.

Comment: The maximal subtree I constructed is like that, yet. *However*, note that this is not the *only* maximal subtree. If you changed the indexing of the vertices and edges, the algorithm might well produce a different maximal subtree.